# React - props is empty when calling a callback function from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button on my main component, when its clicked its open an "Approval pannel", And when the OK is clicked I am calling a callback function to the main component and doing some logic.

I want to pass the callback function(My reasons), The problem is that when the callback function is called, the props and state are undefined.

Why is that happening? Please tell me if any info is missing.

I have added a partial code here:

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
        currentActionConfig = {onOkClick: this.onGenericApprovalOkClicked, ...};
     }

    onCommandApprovalOkClicked(commandText){
        console.log(this.props); <- 'undefined'
    }

    render(){
        return <ActionsApprovalPanel currentActionConfig={this.currentActionConfig}/>
    }
}


export default class ActionsApprovalPanel extends React.Component {
    render() 
    {
        ...
        return <ChangeIpApproval onOkClick={this.props.currentActionConfig.onOkClick}/>;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make few changes to your React component.

**First:** In the constructor call `super()`.

**Second:**: Define `currentActionConfig` as a state and try using it as `this.state.currentActionConfig`

**Third**: Specify the binding on `onCommandApprovalOkClicked()`. as 
           `onCommandApprovalOkClicked = (commandText) => {}` and similary for other functions.

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        currentActionConfig = {onOkClick: this.onGenericApprovalOkClicked, ...}
        };
     }

    onCommandApprovalOkClicked(commandText){
        console.log(this.props); <- 'undefined'
    }

    render(){
        return <ActionsApprovalPanel currentActionConfig={this.state.currentActionConfig}/>
    }
}


export default class ActionsApprovalPanel extends React.Component {

    render() 
    {
        ...
        return <ChangeIpApproval onOkClick={this.props.currentActionConfig.onOkClick}/>;
        ...
    }
}
```

Make these changes and see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes

```
class MainComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props); //1. Call super
        this.currentActionConfig = {onOkClick: this.onGenericApprovalOkClicked.bind(this), ...}; // 2.bind this
     }

    onCommandApprovalOkClicked(commandText){
        console.log(this.props); <- 'undefined'
    }

    render(){
        return <ActionsApprovalPanel currentActionConfig={this.currentActionConfig}/>
    }
}


export default class ActionsApprovalPanel extends React.Component {
    render() 
    {
        ...
        return <ChangeIpApproval onOkClick={this.props.currentActionConfig.onOkClick}/>;
        ...
    }
}
```